# Binary XML file line #..: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I do not understand why I get this error only (for now) on aG alaxy Tab2 (Android 4.1.2 original).
*On the Galaxy S3 (same version of Android) and PC simulation do not receive the error.*
This is my code:

**activity_dialogscore.xml** (where I will put the two fragment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   style="@style/LayoutPaperScore"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:id="@+id/viewflipper_1">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
    android:name="com.didymond.baskstat.FragmentScore"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_score" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
    android:name="com.didymond.baskstat.FragmentStatScore"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_statscore" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

**FragmentScore.java**

```
package com.didymond.baskstat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentScore extends Fragment{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_score, container, false);
    }
}
```

**FragmentStatScore.java**

```
package com.didymond.baskstat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentStatScore extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_statscore, container, false);
    }

}
```

And this is the main activity (only part of it), which uses the two fragment:

**MainFragment.java**

```
public class MainFragment extends FragmentActivity implements AlertDialogChangePlayer.OnDialogDismissListener{

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialogscore);

        [other_code]
    }

    [other_code]
```

}

Why do I get the error only on the Galaxy Tab 2 and not in Galaxy S3 if running on same Android versions?
Any other pieces of code will be inserted if required ...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a layout in a res/layout-* folder?  like res/layout-large?

If you have a separate layout for tablets, the error would only crop up on tablet devices.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have found the error after trying again and carefully reading the error of LogCat.
The real problem is that I use style for setting button ecc...But folder for tablet missing ...For now I have these directory:

```
values
values-hdpi
values-large-mdpi
values-ldpi
values-mdpi
values-small-ldpi
values-v11
values-v14
values-xhdpi
values-xlarge-mdpi
```

To fix the problem I had to add the folder **sw600dp-values​​**.
Now... what other folders should be removed/added?

Ps: the layout folder is unique, in the various values dir there ​​is the file **style.xml** which contains various sizes, etc....